# Damping of value fluctuation, filtering out spikes

Tags: javascript, math

I'm working with physics in JavaScript and I have a value indicating number of contacts in the "physical" world. This value can be between 0 - 6. The problem is that i fluctuates a lot. What I want is to filter out the spikes. Say that number is 3 and then for a fraction of second it changes to zero and then back to 3 again. Any ideas about how to best do this?

Comment: Are we speaking about measured data over time? Can you process it to an array? And maybe the most important, about how much data is it?

Comment: No it's not an array, it's a variable changing overtime, I'm monitoring it using request frame animation 60 times per second. So yes it's about measured data over time :)

Comment: Can't you place a filter method in between that receives a series of let's say 10 digits, and removes all the values that differ to much from the average?

Comment: That could be a solution. Thanks. I'll look in to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Yves-Daoust who pointed me in the direction of the median filter.

More about it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xFaddafLbcg

I made a class for anyone else who have the same problem.
Check it out:

```
MedianFilter = function (size) {

    var that = this;
    that.vales = [];
    that.sorted = [];
    that.size = size || 7;
    that.middelIndex = Math.round(that.size / 2);

};

MedianFilter.prototype = {};

MedianFilter.prototype.input = function (val) {

    var that = this;

    //If it's empty fill it up
    if (that.vales.length === 0) {
        that.fill(val);
        return val;
    }

    //Remove last
    that.vales.shift();
    //Add new value
    that.vales.push(val);

    //Sort
    that.sorted = that.vales.slice(0);
    that.sorted = that.sorted.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b; });
    //return medium value
    return that.sorted[that.middelIndex];

};

MedianFilter.prototype.fill = function (val) {

    var that = this;
    if (that.vales.length === 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < that.size; i++) {
            that.vales.push(val);
        }
    }

};

//Usage

var toucheFix = new MedianFilter(10); //Number is size of array to get median value from, default 7
var val = toucheFix.input(touches); //Apply a median filter to this to make it more stable
```

Answer (score 3):

A good fit can be a median filter in a sliding window. Consider the last N values, where N is at least twice the duration of a drop. Then your filtered value is the median of the N. You repeat forever with the N samples shifted by one position.

As your values are discrete in a tiny range, the median algorithm will be very simple. You keep an histogram of the seven possible values, i.e. seven counters. Whenever you shift by one position, count down the oldest value and count up the new. The median value is such that the cumulated counts reaches N/2.

There will be a certain inertia, i.e. true changes will take some time to be acknowledged, but this is unavoidable because any algorithm needs to confirm a permanent change vs. a temporary drop.

Comment: This was a fantastic solution. Thanks!